# Supress LPSolve IDE output in R

Tags: r

I have created a program to solve certain types of LP problems with the library LPSolveIPE.
When I run the code it displays a message like this:

```
Model name:  '' - run #1    
Objective:   Minimize(R0)
 
SUBMITTED
Model size:      224 constraints,     131 variables,          500 non-zeros.
Sets:                                   0 GUB,                  0 SOS.
 
 
CONSTRAINT CLASSES
General LPSREAL   90
General BIN      112
GUB               22
 
Using DUAL simplex for phase 1 and PRIMAL simplex for phase 2.
The primal and dual simplex pricing strategy set to 'Devex'.
 
Optimized BLAS was successfully loaded for bfp_LUSOL.
Found dual solution with 11 fixed slack variables left basic.
Optimal solution with dual simplex at iter           34.

Relaxed solution              7171.8 after         34 iter is B&B base.
 
get_ptr_sensitivity_objex: Sensitivity unknown
 
Primal objective:
etc...
```

I would like to supress this output if possible. Is there any easy way to do so?

Comment: Maybe [`capture.output`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/capture.output.html) is what you are looking for.